# How to do role-based authorization with Apache Shiro depending on HTTP request method

Tags: rest, basic-authentication, shiro

I'm struggling to figure out how I can do role-based authorization depending on what HTTP method a request is using. I use HTTP basic auth and depending on the users role and the HTTP method used a request should succeed or fail.

Example:

- a GET request to `http://localhost/rest/` should always be allowed, even to non-authenticated users (anon access)
- a PUT request to `http://localhost/rest/` (same resource!) should only be allowed if user is **authenticated**
- a DELETE request to `http://localhost/rest/` (same resource!) should only be allowed if user is **authenticated** and **has the role ADMINISTRATOR**

My current (non-working) attempt of configuring `shiro.ini` looks like this:

```
/rest = authcBasic[PUT], roles[SERVICE_PROVIDER]
/rest = authcBasic[POST], roles[EXPERIMENTER]
/rest = authcBasic[DELETE], roles[ADMINISTRATOR]
/rest = authcBasic
```

**Update**

I've just found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-107 and updated my shiro.ini to be

```
/rest/**:put    = authcBasic, roles[SERVICE_PROVIDER]
/rest/**:post   = authcBasic, roles[EXPERIMENTER]
/rest/**:delete = authcBasic, roles[ADMINISTRATOR]
/rest/**        = authcBasic
```

but it still doesn't work. It seems that only the last rule matches. Also, the commit comment also seems to indicate that this only works with permission-based authorization. Is there no equivalent implementation for role-based authz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation with Shiro and my REST application.  While there may be a better way (I hadn't seen SHIRO-107), my solution was to create a custom filter extending the Authc filter (org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter).  You could do something similar extending the authcBasic filter or the Roles filter (although I think authcBasic would be better as it is probably more complicated).

The method you want to override is "protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue)".  Your argument (e.g. "ADMINISTRATOR") will come in on the mappedValue as String[] where the arguments were split by commas.

Since I needed the possibility of both a method and a role, I ended up have my arguements looks like "-".  For example:

/rest/** = customFilter[DELETE-ADMINISTRATOR]

That let me split out the role required to perform a delete from the role required for a POST by doing something like:

/rest/** = customFilter[DELETE-ADMINISTRATOR,POST-EXPERIMENTER]

I think if you play with this, you'll be able to get the functionality you need.

BTW, I hadn't seen SHIRO-107, so I've not tried that technique and probably won't since I've already invented my own custom filter. However that may provide a cleaner solution than what I did.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks a lot for the suggestion. In fact, while you were writing this I got to the same idea and I have implemented it by now. I think it's good whatsoever that this solution is posted here on StackOverflow. I'll try to see if the guys at the Shiro project are interested in taking my implementation as a contribution...

Answer (score 1):

I think HttpMethodPermissionFilter is the one you need to configure: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authz/HttpMethodPermissionFilter.html  This should enable you to map the HTTP method to Shiro's "create,read,update,delete" permissions as outlined in the javadoc for the class.